# ParseQuery in a For Loop from array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, angular

Sorry if I don't write well, I'm french.

I have an array of items like this :

```
items = [
        {nom: 'xxx', prenom: 'zzz', montant: 500},
        {nom: 'aaa', prenom: 'bbb', montant: 1000},
        {nom: 'ccc', prenom: 'ddd', montant: 1500}
    ];
```

I want to do a Parse query on each item of this array to retrieve information from my stored datas on Parse.com. I did this :

```
for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {           

        query.equalTo("nomTiers", items[x].nom);
        console.log('Loop ' + x);

        query.first({
            success: function (result) {
                nom = result.get('nomTiers');
                prenom = result.get('prenTiers');
                console.log(nom + ' ' + prenom);
                console.log('Entered success');
                lesCollab.push({
                    nom: nom,
                    prenom: prenom
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // if it fails...
            }
        });   
    }
```

When I look the Log console on my browser i see this :

```
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
...
Entered success
Entered success
...
```

It means my app start to launch the code inside my for loop but never launch my parse query. It did it only after my For loop ends. Because of that i can't do what i want properly and I don't understand why the code act like this...

How can I run my query each time my for loops ? Why the query is run AFTER my for ?

Comment: By default all xhr requests are asyc in nature, you need to handle it through promise/callback or observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the `first` method of `ParseQuery` is asynchronous since it involves an HTTP call. You need to wait for the `success` callback to be called before handling the next element of your array.

For this you need to leverage promises. In your case, you can create a loop function that that calls itself when the promise returns by the provided callback is resolved:

```
const loop = (g) => {
  return new Promise((f, r) => {
    return g().then(v => loop(g)).catch(f);
  });
};
```

You can then use it to implement your asynchronous loop:

```
var x = 0;
loop(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    query.equalTo("nomTiers", items[x].nom);
    query.first(this.items[x], {
      success: (result) => {
        nom = result.get('nomTiers');
        prenom = result.get('prenTiers');
        console.log(nom + ' ' + prenom);
        console.log('Entered success');
        this.lesCollab.push({
          nom: nom,
          prenom: prenom
        });
        x++;
        if (x<this.items.length) {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

An additional wrapping into a promise is necessary since `ParseQuery` isn't promise-compliant.

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/r4qb67N0FLoPWOPNbM5w?p=preview. I used a `fakeQueryFirst` that can be replaced by `query.first`.

The async library could also interest you with its [`each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function:

```
async.each(items, (item, cb) => {var x = 0;
  query.equalTo("nomTiers", items[x].nom);
  query.first(this.items[x], {
    success: (result) => {
      nom = result.get('nomTiers');
      prenom = result.get('prenTiers');
      console.log(nom + ' ' + prenom);
      console.log('Entered success');
      this.lesCollab.push({
        nom: nom,
        prenom: prenom
      });
      cb();
    }
  });
});
```